Dynamic query parameters
I implement FastAPI, SQLAlchemy service that has integration with ERM software. ERM software stores data in table as
Class Table():
   main_option_1: Any
   main_option_2: Any

class ExtraOption():
   extra_option: Any

class TableExtraOption():
   table_id: FK
   extra_option_id: FK
   value: Any

Basically, I did it. But the next step is to get list of Table records. And it is not a big deal. But the problem arises when I try to filter the queryset using query parameters by fields I don't know and I even don't know how many fields I have.
Filters are stored as:
class CategoryOfTable():
   name: str

class FilterCategory():
   option: str (it maybe both main option and extra option)
   category_id: FK
   order: int (order of that uses frontend to show filter)

In general, it will be good to solve this issue this way because if somebody adds extra options and extra filters in ERM they will upload in my service by event and I won't add any migrations manually.
I read some questions at stackoverflow and decided to use pydantic schema for query parameters this way:
class ExtraOptionValueQuerySchema(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None


class ExtraOptionQuerySchema(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    item: Optional[List[ExtraOptionValueQuerySchema]] = Depends()


class RecordQuerySchema(BaseModel):
    length_gt: Optional[float] = None
    length_lt: Optional[float] = None
    width_gt: Optional[float] = None
    width_lt: Optional[float] = None
    height_gt: Optional[float] = None
    height_lt: Optional[float] = None
    weight_gt: Optional[float] = None
    weight_lt: Optional[float] = None
    brand: Optional[str] = None
    extra_options: Optional[List[ExtraOptionQuerySchema]] = Depends()


@app.get("")
async def get_records(
    category_id: uuid_pkg.UUID, request: Request, query: RecordQuerySchema = Depends(), db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)
) -> None:
    pass

And I'm not able to check whether it works or not because required kwargs and args appears (exactly kwargs and args that's the name of query parameters). Is it basically implementable? Do you have any ideas about it?

Could this be an alternative approach?

I don't know exactly but idea seems to be interesting. Thank you

@Chris no it is not the solution in my case. the more i search, the more i realize that this is probably impossible

If somebody has the same problems as me than I decided to use POST request where all parameters I send as a json.

In that case, you might find this answer, as well as this answer and this answer helpful
